# Error with Custom Connector on PowerBI Enterprise Gateway: ExtensionDataSourceKind

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-datasource

I built a customer connector to access the Vimeo API through OAuth2. The connector works locally on PowerBI Desktop, and is also works on a Personal Gateway. Unfortunately, when I try and deploy it on my company's Enterprise Gateway, I get the following error:

[image]

`Extension{"extensionDataSourceKind":"_VimeoConnector","extensionDataSourcePath":"https://api.vimeo.com/users/{our-user-id}/videos"}`

The ability to refresh custom connectors has been allowed on this gateway. Also, the Vimeo connector is recognized by the gateway and is online and working:

[image]

I have seen the Extension{"extensionDataSourceKind" error mentioned around the net, but have not seen a clear answer as to why it occurs. I would greatly appreciate any help from the community on what steps I should take next.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution? I am facing the same issue now.